# How to pass a variable to query string in Drive Api

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I want to pass a query to my drive where the query checks for a particular folder ID.

```
q="'1gVe3Mktuo05xaCMAnr4nA6kvEqnEhiUX' in parents and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
```

I want to make this query dynamic by storing the ID of a folder in a vairable and then appending it to the query. This is what I tried:

`q= user_id+" in parents and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'`"

But this is not working.

This is the code:

```
user_folder_id = service.files().list(q="name = 'users'",spaces = 'drive').execute()   
    user_folder_details = user_folder_id.get('files', [])
    for i in user_folder_details:
        user_id = i['id']
        type = i['mimeType']

     results = service.files().list(q= user_id+" in parents and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",spaces = 'drive').execute()   
    items = results.get('files', [])


    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
```

Comment: Parents isnt a user id its a file id you realise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your query to work you need to add single quotes. So instead of this:

```
q= user_id+" in parents and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
```

To this:

```
q= "'" + user_id + "' in parents and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
```

Also you could try to use [.format()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) or [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) to make this more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Use %s to format the query. Worked for me e.g.

`"'%s' in parents and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'" % (user_id)`

Will also work when querying name of folder e.g

`name = 'folder_name'`

`folderNameQuery = "name = '%s' and (mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-  apps.folder')" % (name)`